# Image resizing in loop sometimes return incomplete or black images

Tags: php, curl, image-resizing

I've got a bunch of image links I need to download locally on the server. Most requests works fine but every now and then when the job runs scheduled night time, it returns black images. The source is checked and gives the right image.

Rarely it also returns black images with the actual picture in the top left corner but very small.

The array contains about 150 images to get and resize.

First, I download the file:

```
function downloadFile($url, $path) {
    $file = basename($url);
    $source = file_get_contents($url);
    $fp = fopen($path. $file, 'w');
    set_time_limit(0);
    $options = array(
      CURLOPT_FILE    => $fp,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800, 
      CURLOPT_URL     => $fp,
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    curl_exec($ch);


    fwrite($fp, $source);

    fclose($fp);
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Then resize it:

```
   function Img_Resize($path) {

       $x = getimagesize($path);            
       $width  = $x['0'];
       $height = $x['1'];

       $rs_width  = 245;//resize to half of the original width.
       $rs_height = 163;//resize to half of the original height.

       switch ($x['mime']) {
          case "image/gif":
             $img = imagecreatefromgif($path);
             break;
          case "image/jpeg":
             $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
             break;
          case "image/jpg":
             $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
             break;
          case "image/png":
             $img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
             break;
       }

       $img_base = imagecreatetruecolor($rs_width, $rs_height);
       imagesetinterpolation($img_base, IMG_BICUBIC);
       imagecopyresampled($img_base, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $rs_width, $rs_height, $width, $height);

       $path_info = pathinfo($path);    
       switch ($path_info['extension']) {
          case "gif":
             imagegif($img_base, $path);  
             break;
          case "jpeg":
             imagejpeg($img_base, $path);  
             break;
          case "jpg":
             imagejpeg($img_base, $path);  
             break;
          case "png":
             imagepng($img_base, $path);  
             break;
       }

    }
```

As follows:

```
foreach ($URLimages as &$value) {
    if (strpos($value->image, '.jpg')) {
    downloadFile($value->image, $path);
    $test = basename($value->image);
    $img = Img_Resize($path . $test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do curl return black images or is after the resize happens?

Comment: Not sure, this only happens in production so I can't go by trial and error. But regarding the incomplete images it may be the resizing that causes it.

Comment: @Pafjo I changed the title

Comment: Your code seems to do very little error checking on the success or failure of each operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downloadFile seems to assume everything 'just works'. Life and programming isn't like this.

Below is some of the areas where I would expect a possible error and do something if it happened. You can do this in other ways if you want, such as using [try...catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and throwing exceptions.

```php
$source = file_get_contents($url);
if (!$source) { // failed - retry or take other action
    return false;
}

$fp = fopen($path. $file, 'w');
if (!$fp) { // file didn't open ...
    return false;
}

$ch = curl_init();
if (!$ch) { // curl session didn't start ...
    return false;
}

if (!curl_exec( $ch)) { // curl session didn't work
    return false;
}

if (!fwrite($fp, $source)) { // data didn't get written to file
    return false;
}


// return success
return true;
}
```

Your main code should not try to generate an image for failed downloads:

```
foreach ($URLimages as &$value) {
  if (strpos($value->image, '.jpg')) {
    if (downloadFile($value->image, $path)) {
      $test = basename($value->image);
      $img = Img_Resize($path . $test);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and not CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS?

28800 Seconds for timeout seems very high.
If you have set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS on a different place to a lower value, the lowest value is taken.

When downloading a file takes longer than your timeout you'll get an incomplete file...

Comment: I agree. Added it to the code. Doesn't resolve the issue though.

Comment: As already posted by vogomatix you should also handle an incomplete download.  For debugging I would store the original downloaded file, so you can narrow down the problem (download problem or resizing problem)